# SSH permission denied,Load key pem.file": Is a directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I try to connect to my Linux instance.This is the verbose output

```
ssh -v -i ~/kljuc/pem.file ubuntu@ec2-52-29-225-243.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-29-225-243.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com [52.29.225.243] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/holmes/kljuc/pem.file type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/holmes/kljuc/pem.file-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-52-29-225-243.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:PVlbK2oKtW3ZAIW/usx9IBKw9mjeTwfoGMhl4THBzl8
debug1: Host 'ec2-52-29-225-243.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/holmes/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: holmes@holmes-System-Product-Name
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/holmes/kljuc/pem.file
Load key "/home/holmes/kljuc/pem.file": Is a directory
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is the pem file after chmod 400

```
ls -la pem.file
ls: cannot access 'pem.file/mm-aws1.pem': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'pem.file/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'pem.file/.': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? mm-aws1.pem
```

I have seen the previous answers.How can I check if I have messed up with pem file?
Should I create new Key Pair?
Or new instance with new Key Pair?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are not pointing the .pem file in the ssh command(-i ~/kljuc/pem.file).

**Try like:** `ssh -v -i ~/kljuc/pem.file/mm-aws1.pem ubuntu@ec2-52-29-225-243.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

1. Have the pem file name with .pem extension(Ex:somename.pem). Also make sure .pem file content should start with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and ends with "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
2. make sure .pem file has necessary permission else run

`chmod 400 somename.pem`